# find start and end in a series of string and number combination

Tags: python, list

I have a several points, named by letter plus number. It can be: A1, AA1, A01, AA01...

I have a bunch of them in a list and I want to get a output using "-" to replace intervals.

For example, `lst = ['RB11', 'RB12', 'A08', 'A09', 'A10', 'SN13', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']` and I wanna get `['RB11-12','A08-10','SN13,'A1-4']`

thank you very much!

I'm thinking about to:

- split letter and number
- if repeated letter is found, extract string with that letter
- get first and last string
- repeat and create a new list

Comment: Your approach seems good, but what happens if you have ['A1', 'A2', 'A4', 'A3']?

Comment: What I mean is, in your example all letters are grouped and all numbers are concurrent (In order and with no gaps), if you have `['A1','B1','A3','B4','A2']`, is that still `A1-3` and `B1-4` even though `B3` is missing?

Comment: I used "sorted" so  elements are in ascending order

Comment: What about gaps? Would `['B1','B4']` be B1-4 or separate points since B2 and B3 are missing?

Comment: that's a good point. I need to think about it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the elements:

```py
import re
from itertools import groupby


def key_fn(val):
    return re.match(r"([A-Z]+)(\d+)", val).groups()


lst = ["RB11", "RB12", "A08", "A09", "A10", "SN13", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"]

out = []
for k, g in groupby(map(key_fn, lst), lambda k: k[0]):
    match list(g):
        case [f, *_, l]:
            out.append(f"{f[0]}{f[1]}-{l[1]}")
        case [f]:
            out.append(f"{f[0]}{f[1]}")

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['RB11-12', 'A08-10', 'SN13', 'A1-4']
```

Comment: wow seems great! let me try. thanks.

Comment: thank you for your code. I've tried with different input lists and found it will encounter an error if input include, let's say, 'A1' and 'A4' only. The code will treat it as "*_" case and comes out as "A1-4".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try that:

```
import re

# Sorting alphanumeric points.
# Use a regular expression to split each point into letters and numbers,
def custom_sort_key(point):
    match = re.match(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)', point)  # Search for letters and numbers in the point
    return (match.group(1), int(match.group(2)))  # Return tuple

# Take a list of alphanumeric points and groups consecutive points into intervals.
def group_intervals(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    lst.sort(key=custom_sort_key)  # Sort the list using custom key
    intervals = []
    start, end = lst[0], lst[0]  # Initialize start and end variables with first point
    for point in lst[1:]:
        # Check if the current point is consecutive to the previous one
        if custom_sort_key(point) == (custom_sort_key(end)[0], custom_sort_key(end)[1] + 1):
            end = point  # If consecutive, update the end point
        else:
            # If not consecutive, add the interval to the list of intervals
            intervals.append(f"{start}-{end}" if start != end else start)
            start, end = point, point  # Update the start and end points
    # Add the last interval or point to the list of intervals
    intervals.append(f"{start}-{end}" if start != end else start)
    return intervals

lst = ['RB11', 'RB12', 'A08', 'A09', 'A10', 'SN13', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4', 'A3']
result = group_intervals(lst)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that only consecutive (non-interrupted) sequences are grouped, you can use the difference between the number part and the position in the sorted list.  Consecutive numbers will have the same difference and thus can be grouped together using `itertools.groupby`.

Because of the letter prefix, the grouping key should actually be the combination of the letter prefix with that position difference:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst    = ['RB11', 'RB12', 'A08', 'A09', 'A10', 'SN13', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']

def parts(code):
    L = code.strip("0123456789")
    return L,int(code[len(L):])

lst.sort(key=parts)
keys   = ( (L,n-i) for i,(L,n) in enumerate(map(parts,lst)) )
groups = [ G[0] + G[-1].replace(L,'-')*(len(G)>1)
           for (L,_),(*G,) in groupby(lst,key=lambda _:next(keys)) ]


print(groups)
['A1-4', 'A08-10', 'RB11-12', 'SN13']
```

- the `parts` function converts the letter/number code into a tuple with the letter prefix separated from the numeric part (which is stored as an integer to allow proper sorting and computation).
- the `keys` generator returns the grouping tuples in the same sorted order as the list converting the numeric parts into their difference with the sorted position.
- using `groupby` with the grouping keys, produces a group identifier (composed of a letter prefix and a difference to position) with the list of  corresponding letter/number codes from the original list.
- the `groups` resulting list formats the combined string using the first and last codes of the group (without the range indicator when the group only has one item)