# In python how can i convert a list of numbers to a crontab format

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a list of numbers like `[1,2,3,6]`
How can I convert this list to a string `'1-3,6'` to be used in a crontab rule ?

Or for example `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` to be converted in `'1-6'`
Or for example `[1,2,0]` to `'0-2'`

I know how sorting works but I can not figure out how to 'group' numbers to this format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find start and end in a series of string and number combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77036641/find-start-and-end-in-a-series-of-string-and-number-combination)

Comment: @Daviid, after looking at your link, though the problems are similar, they're not the same (the grouping function is simpler in the case you linked).

Answer (score 3):

Using itertools:

This will group consecutive numbers:

```
import itertools

list_num = [1,2,3,5,6]

groups = (list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(list_num, lambda x, c=itertools.count(): x - next(c)))

print(', '.join('-'.join(map(str, (item[0], item[-1])[:len(item)])) for item in groups))

#output
1-3, 5-6
```

Edit:

This will convert `[1,2,0]` to `1-2, 0`. If you want the answer to be `0-2` you need to sort the list then apply the above answer.

Comment: Nice, I was trying to build a function for groupby, but yours is more elegant than what I came to!

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, though it's far less elegant than Talha's answer, I'll still post mine. Here too, the list should be sorted beforehand:

```
from itertools import accumulate, groupby

list_num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 30,31]

list_gap = accumulate([list_num[i+1]-list_num[i]-1 for i in range(len(list_num)-1)], initial=0)
# for those curious, list(list_gap) is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 21, 21]
# (a - b for a, b in zip(list_num, range(len(list_num)))) would have been simpler...

list_grouped = groupby(list_num, key=lambda _: next(list_gap))

range_string = ', '.join('-'.join((g[0], g[-1])) for _, group in list_grouped for g in [list(map(str, group))])

# '1-5, 8-10, 30-31'
```